# Bouncy Castle - Diffie Hellman Secrets do not match

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, diffie-hellman

I am using Bouncy castle library to use DH key exchange. So far i have tried this much but keys seem to not match. What am i doing wrong? PLEASE HELP!

```
        var p = Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger.ProbablePrime(1024, new Random());
        var g = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger("5");

        var importedParameters = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.DHParameters(p, g);

        //---------------------bob---------------------------------------------------
        var scrnd = new SecureRandom();
        var bobkeyGen = GeneratorUtilities.GetKeyPairGenerator("DH");
        var kgp = new DHKeyGenerationParameters(scrnd, importedParameters);
        bobkeyGen.Init(kgp);
        var bobasypair = bobkeyGen.GenerateKeyPair();

        var dhPublicKeyParameters = bobasypair.Public as DHPublicKeyParameters;
        var dhPrivateKeyParameters = bobasypair.Private as DHPrivateKeyParameters;

        var internalKeyAgree = AgreementUtilities.GetBasicAgreement("DH");
        internalKeyAgree.Init(dhPrivateKeyParameters);
        var secret = internalKeyAgree.CalculateAgreement(dhPublicKeyParameters);

        //-----------------------------alice--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        var alicekeyGen = GeneratorUtilities.GetKeyPairGenerator("DH");
        var allkgp = new DHKeyGenerationParameters(scrnd, importedParameters);
        alicekeyGen.Init(allkgp);
        var aliceasypair = alicekeyGen.GenerateKeyPair();

        var alicedhPublicKeyParameters = aliceasypair.Public as DHPublicKeyParameters;
        var alicedhPrivateKeyParameters = aliceasypair.Private as DHPrivateKeyParameters;

        var allinternalKeyAgree = AgreementUtilities.GetBasicAgreement("DH");
        allinternalKeyAgree.Init(alicedhPrivateKeyParameters);
        var tobesamesecret = allinternalKeyAgree.CalculateAgreement(alicedhPublicKeyParameters);

        if (!secret.Equals(tobesamesecret))
            throw new Exception();
```

Comment: The key agreement must use your private key and **their** public key. You're using your private key and your public key, which is incorrect.

Comment: Hello again,
Thanks for that.
I am trying to read a .pem file which has the DH params. How would I convert the bytes to DHParams?. I think i am doing something wrong.I am using C# version of Bouncy Castle.                                                          using (var stream = new StreamReader("dhparam.pem"))
            {
                var reader = new PemReader(stream);
                
                var pemObj = reader.ReadPemObject();
                
                importedbytes = pemObj.Content;

                
            }